# 'Trainer' or 'Coach'

Tags: word-choice

How to call a person who teaches people to speed-read (preferrably in Am. E.)? A trainer seems too old-fashioned for me, while the word "coach" doesn't exactly fit this scope of activity and sound more like something belonging to sport. Maybe there is some other suitable word for that? Speed-reading tutor/mentor/or maybe simply teacher?

Answer (score 2):

Trainer, coach, tutor, mentor, and teacher are all fine. The differences between the words are the same in this context as in any other.